# How do I return <empty> from OO-CALC IF-statement?

Tags: openoffice-calc

Using OpenOffice CALC v4.1.3.
The dataset contains 400,000 rows and I am looking for the rows that are not in sequence order in column B.  Column B contains integers from 1,2,3, etc. to the last row of data.

I am trying to set the cells in column-A with the formula as follow:

```
=IF(B3 = (B2+1);[empty];"BAD SEQUENCE")
```

I do not want to have the TRUE part to be "" (empty-string).
I want it to be [empty] or [blank] or [null] or [no-value] or [nothing] (using other language words here) 
because I want to be able to use the [shift]+[down-arrow] key combination to find the next BAD-SEQUENCE row(s).

When the set of cells is actually [empty] then the [shift]+[down-arrow] navigates to the next "cell-with-value" (if not [empty]).

In this question, I have presented the code to show [empty] but I need the proper OO-CALC representation of [empty] to have empty cells when the if-statement is TRUE.

Your comments and solutions are welcome...thanks John

Comment: When I tried this, the relevant key sequence was Ctrl+Down.  Shift+Down simply expanded the selection by 1 row at a time, regardless of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://superuser.com/questions/346873/openoffice-calc-how-to-insert-blank-in-a-formula:

> No value will make isblank return true, because C1 will always contain a formula, and isblank literally tests for blanks. Not empty strings, but actual empty cells.

Like [ISBLANK](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ISBLANK_function), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> considers any formula to be non-empty, regardless of its result.

Instead, do the following workaround:

- Use `""` as the [empty] value.
- Copy column A.
- Select an unused column such as column C.
- Paste Special, with the Formulas box unchecked.

Alternatively, instead of using formulas, fill column A with values using a macro.

Comment: Thank you for your workaround -- It worked perfectly.  I mark this as the answer...thanks, again.

Comment: --  CTRL+DOWN is correct -- I wrote the SHIFT by mistake.  Sorry and Thanks.